# Forward with another template

Tags: php, templates, symfony

I'm facing a problem with the `forward` method of Symfony (v2.3).

Basicly, I have two controllers in two distinct bundles. Let's say `DesktopBundle` for a desktop version of the app, and `MobileBundle` for the mobile version.

I want to reuse code of an action of the `DesktopBundle` into an action of `MobileBundle`. What I do now is a forward :

**DesktopController**

```php
namespace Acme\DesktopBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="desktopIndex")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /* some code I don't want to duplicate */

        return array(
            'some' => 'var'
        );
    }
}
```

**MobileController**

```php
namespace Acme\MobileBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="mobileIndex")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->forward('AcmeDesktopBundle:Index:index');
    }
}
```

Now it works, but obviously the `Response` object is returned with the rendered template of the desktop version of the `indexAction`.

What I would like, is to get the variables and then render the template of the mobile version.

What I tried is to pass a variable into the forward method and then render the action conditionally into the desktop version:

```php
return $this->forward(
    'acmeDesktopBundle:Index:index', 
    array('mobile' => true)
);
```

This would work, but I don't really want to change to code inside the `DesktopBundle` but only the `MobileBundle`. Is there a way to achieve this ? I am missing something, or should I go to an entirely different solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forwarding means to redirect to the given page, but without changing the url on the client. I.e. redirect on the server side. If you want only access the return value of the action, simply call it. With the `@Template` annotation this is made very easy.

```
namespace Acme\MobileBundle\Controller;

use Acme\DesktopBundle\Controller\IndexController as DesktopController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="mobileIndex")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $desktop = new DesktopController();
        $desktop->setContainer($this->container);

        $values = $desktop->indexAction();
        // do something with it

        return $values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one but I throws me this error : `FatalErrorException</abbr>: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 251`